# Create comma separated value from multiple fields

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have between 1-10 form fields posted to a php script that collects the values from existing fields and use that data

Since I am trying to change some functions on the site to ajax I wonder how I can, with jquery, find all the fields with the name `amount-*`and put their values in a comma separated string and then post it to the server side script via ajax like this:

*New code*

```
$("#div").load("/serverscript.php", {ids:commaSeparatedValues}
```

*Old code*

```
while(isset($_POST['amount-'.$indexCount])){
  $changedCartAmount = $changedCartAmount . $_POST['amount-'.$indexCount] . ',';
  $indexCount++;
}
$changedCartAmount = substr($changedCartAmount,0,-1);
$arrayChangedCartAmount = explode(",",$changedCartAmount);
```

Comment: @ closer: What is difficult to understand here? Looks pretty obvious.
Not practical, but obvious.

Comment: I advice you to edit your question and ask only the second part (find all fields.. put values in comma separated string..) otherwise people will Close this question.

Comment: @Joseph - if you do that, your clients can never use your form with JS disabled. Is that a Good Thing?

Comment: @mpl from the title one might think the OP is just asking to translate some code - personally I've read the whole thing, but many are quick on the close trigger and don't bother.

Comment: @Sha I agree. I do not like the trigger happiness here. Slightly less annoying than commentless downvoters but still

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var commaSeparatedValues = [];
$("[name^='amount-']").each(function() {
  var val = this.value; // using the raw field value rather than $(this).val();
  if (val.length>0) commaSeparatedValues.push(val);
}
$("#div").load("/serverscript.php", {ids:commaSeparatedValues.join(",")}
```

Comment: I would use array then `join` it, more elegant then appending to a string.

Comment: Nice! I would also improve efficiency even further by using the raw `this.value` (no need to wrap it with `$`) and finally not store empty values although I believe it's handled in the server side code. :)

Comment: Aha - I always worry about $(this) vs this

Comment: Yeah, no need for wrapping. One (hopefully) last thing - having `if (val.length > 0)` is enough, it will never be undefined or null - just empty string in case user didn't type anything. Unless of course there will be elements other than `<input>` with that name - to bust this change the selector to `$("input[name^='amount-']")`

Comment: I have seen the length test, however that will not work if there is no value returned. I know in older Mozillas you would get an undefined if you inquired about the value on an `<input type="text" name="bla">`

Comment: Didn't know that.. well, maybe `if ($(this).val().length > 0)` then as I'm sure jQuery is doing all the necessary checkings.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var commaSeperatedValues = "";
$("[name^='amount-']").each(function(){
    commaSeperatedValues += $(this).val() + ","; //or you can use this.value
});
commaSeperatedValues = commaSeperatedValues.replace(/,$/, "")

$("#div").load("/serverscript.php", {ids:commaSeparatedValues});
```

Comment: HoHum. I must learn to not make any comments to the question and then type faster